# Scapy не имеет атрибут arping

Tags: python, kali-linux, scapy

При запуске скрипта:

```
from scapy.all import *

def scaner(ip):
    scapy.arping(ip)

scaner("10.0.2.1")
```

в терминале на `Kali Linux` падает ошибка:

```
Errors: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/PycharmProjects/net_scan/net_scan.py", line 8, in <module>
    scaner("10.0.2.1")
  File "/home/kali/PycharmProjects/net_scan/net_scan.py", line 6, in scaner
    scapy.arping(ip)
AttributeError: module 'scapy' has no attribute 'arping'
```

Как решить проблему?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Переустанови пакет `Scapy`. Поочередно в терминале выполни команды:

```
pip uninstall scapy   
pip install --pre scapy[complete]
```

Проблема должна быть решена. И ещё, погугли, что такое `virtualenv` и с чем его едят. Старайся работать через виртуальное окружение.

ЗЫ Импортируй `scapy` немного иначе. Пример кода ниже:

```
import scapy.all as scapy

def scaner(ip):
    scapy.arping(ip)

scaner("10.0.2.1")
```